# Android and fuse.conf

Tags: android, config, root, mount, fuse

I am trying to find the fuse.conf file or anything that is similar to it that allows me to enable user_allow_other. I looked for it everywhere starting from /etc/fuse.conf and ending with a full search. Is it possible to enable user_allow_other on my android device.

Thank you.

P.S. The device is rooted.

Comment: I cannot find any reason for anyone to down vote a question without even leaving a reply. If you have something to say, say it. Do not just downvote and leave. I wish stackoverflow would add this option to force people to leave a reply before downvoting. Then, we will have a fully  productive and useful discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem. 
Looks like it's hardcoded in /bin/sdcard binary

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-cts-5.1_r8/sdcard/sdcard.c#1839

```
snprintf(opts, sizeof(opts),            
 "fd=%i,rootmode=40000,default_permissions,allow_other,user_id=%d,group_id=%d",fd, uid, gid);
```